# How to use jQuery val() and show the value as text in html body

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  - this is saying to wait until document is ready before          calling function

  $("button").click(function(){ - this is saying when "button" is click to perform function.

    alert("Value: " + $("#test").val()); - this is saying to show value in pop up box.
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse"></p> - this is input for the value

<button>Show Value</button> - this is the button. 
</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering how I can have the value show in the html body instead of the pop up box. I was thinking I could use a $(selector).document.write function, but it doesn't seem to work. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign values to body using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('body').append( $("#test").val());
```

or assign to specific element using id selector

```
$('#divId').append( $("#test").val());
```

or assign to specific element using class selector

```
$('.cssClassName').append( $("#test").val());
```

or show it using document.write

```
document.write($("#test").val());
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! Isn't it possible to use $(document).write as well some how? I remember seeing an example using that in the html body or it only possible with Javascript? I just can't remember exactly how it was done.

Comment: You can do it like this, document.write($("#test").val());

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get to work using .append, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the .document.write($("#value").val()); to work, but I'll figure it out:     $(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('#paragraph2').append($('#value').val());
 });
 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="value"></p>
<p id='paragraph2'></p>
<button>Show Value</button